# Should data layer implementations be inside data layer if they depend on platform?

Tags: android, clean-architecture

Let's say we have the following graph. Should `LocalStorage` be in the data layer even though it depends on the platform ? Should we have a separate module called `data-android` for example that has these kinds of implementations ?

Edit: maybe actually the right move here is to move the `Repository` and `ILocalStorage` to the domain layer since they only contain business logic. That's probably where this misunderstanding is coming from. This way the data layer will become easily replaceable by just implementing the contracts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: maybe actually the right move here is to move the Repository and ILocalStorage to the domain layer since they only contain business logic. That's probably where this misunderstanding is coming from. This way the data layer will become easily replaceable by just implementing the contracts.

I completely agree with this, you `ILocalStorasge` should be out of the implementation and your repository needs to know only that are working with an ILocalStorage and it is sure that can call some method that the interface specification.

With this logic, you can have multiple implementations of LocalStorage, with different techniques for different platforms.